# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to oracle 11g XE through hibernate in my application.
when I deploy the application in tomcat(7.0) i m getting the below message.

> java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the
>   following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of
>   SID given in connect descriptor

When I run the application and call the request to the Dao class through UI I am getiing below exception message.

> org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not
>   get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
>   Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505,
>   TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect
>   descriptor

My DB properties file is

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver 
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:XE
jdbc.username=system
jdbc.password=oracle
```

i have installed oracle11g XE and theses are my tnanames.ora and listener.ora files. Where should I make change.

listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\oracleXE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\oracleXE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SIPLDT0019-PC)(PORT = 1522))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SIPLDT0019-PC)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

SID Is the 'unique name for your DDBB'.

You must give it in the connection url like this:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<IP-PORT>/<your_SID>?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=ISO-8859-1
```

In this case this was a postgres db and the url was in the datasource definition in an apache-tomcat server (server.xml) (Inside ).

(You can configure too hibernate's pool adding:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://<IP-PORT>/<your_SID></property>
```

)

Is not the same but you can figure that you should insert the DDBB SID somewhere in the url specification.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can u please elaborate. here i m using oracle 11g xe.

Comment: u can see in my question the url i have given

Comment: Should be something like:

`jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:XE/<your_ddbb_SID>`

Or:

`jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:XE/<your_ddbb_SID>/`

The SID is the name of the root container of your tables when you use the DDBB explorer -whatever GUI you use-

Comment: The SID is the name of the root item container of your tables when you use the DDBB explorer -whatever GUI you use-. It should have like childs something like 'tables', 'schemas', 'functions'...

Comment: I am not using any GUI. I am using oracle database command prompt

Comment: So SID is the name with which you created the DDBB. You know: myddbb... mybigenterprisename... 

Anyway you must say to your database command prompt what is our DDBB's SID before connect to it in order to let it know where must it connect to. You will tell it, probabilly: ip, port, SID, user and password